# Stabilität vs Stabilisierung

Tags: grammatical-case

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen der beiden? soweit ich verstehe, Stabilität ist eine echte Name aber Stabilisierung wird vom Verb stabilisieren substantiviert, gibt es andere Unterscheide? sozusagen eins wird in der Öffentlichkeit genutzt und die andere nur beim Schreiben

Answer (score 9):

Die Wörter haben verschiedene Bedeutungen.

Die **Stabilität** ist ein Zustand. Das System ist stabil.
Die **Stabilisierung** ist ein Vorgang. Man will die Stabilität erreichen

Man kann sehr oft auf ähnlicher Weise aus Adjektiven Verben und Substantive bilden

> mobil
>     → die Mobilität
>     → mobilisieren → die Mobilisierung

Comment: gilt das auch für alle Namen, die zweiförmiger Form haben wie Sexualität und Sexualisierung usw?

Comment: @AmarAlsyed Ja. Sprache ist zwar oft willkürlich, aber Derivationsendungen wie "-ierung" sind sehr regelmäßig in der Bedeutung.