# Professionalität vs. Professionalisierung vs. Professionalismus

Tags: meaning

Gibt es Unterschiede zwischen den Wörtern? Soweit ich weiß, sind "Professionalität/-smus" echte Wörter, aber "Professionalisierung" ist eine substantivierte Form.

Comment: Fast ein Duplikat von https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49602/stabilit%c3%a4t-vs-stabilisierung

Answer (score 3):

Ich beziehe mich hier in erster Linie auf [diese Publikation](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/zpt.2016.68.issue-2/zpt-2016-0017/zpt-2016-0017.pdf), in der die Begriffe noch weiter diskutiert werden.

> **Professionalität** [...] ist an Praxis gebunden und beschreibt eine spezifische Qualität des beruflichen Handelns
>
> **Professionalisierung** verweist [...] einerseits auf die Profession als Ganze (Professionwerdung), andererseits auf die Prozesse der Entwicklung von Professionalität
>
> während **Professionalismus** das damit verbundene Selbstverständnis bezeichnet

Den Professionalismus ergänzend will ich noch auf [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Professionalismus) verweisen, das es wie folgt beschreibt

> das Ausüben einer Tätigkeit (meist einer Sportart) als Beruf

bzw diese [Seite](http://www.wirtschaftslexikon.co/d/professionalismus/professionalismus.htm), die Professionalismus als

> universelle Leistungsorientierung betonende Berufsauffassung

bezeichnet.

Answer (score 2):

*Professionalität* beschreibt wie andere Fremdwörter mit -ität (Sexualität, Authentizität, Sozialität, Nationalität) einen **Zustand**, bzw. die dauerhafte Ausübung eines Tuns. Hier: *Das Professionell-Sein*.

*Professionalisierung* beschreibt ein **Werden**, also die Entwicklung hin zu einem Zustand. Hier: *Das Professionell-Werden*.

*Professionalismus* beschreibt dagegen ein **Wollen**, ein Streben nach dem Zustand des Professionell-Seins.

Answer (score 0):

Der gängigste Begriff ist **Professionalität**. Er bezeichnet, das man etwas berufstätig macht. Laut Duden ein Synonym (also gleichbedeutend hierzu) ist der **Professionalismus**, wobei mir persönlich dieser Begriff noch nie über den Weg gelaufen ist.

**Professionalisierung** hat aber eine andere Bedeutung: sie beschreibt den Prozess hin zur Professionalität. Wenn man also zum Beispiel sein Hobby zum Beruf macht, oder etwas, was man bisher nur nebenbei betrieben hat plötzlich professionell betreibt, dann ist dieser Prozess die **Professionalisierung**.

Comment: professionalität/smus sind ein Zustand demgegenüber ist "professionalisierung" ein Vorgang oder einen Prozess, bin ich richtig ?

Comment: Die Frage ist sinnvoll und berechtigt. Bezüglich der Endungen ...ieren, ...ierung, und auch  ... ation könnte sie jetzt noch 1000 mal gestellt werden. Die Antworten wären im Prinzip immer dieselben.

Comment: _-ität_ und _-ismus_ würde ich nicht als Synonyme ansehen. Beim Vergleich mit _Nationalität/Nationalismus_ oder _Rationalität/Rationalismus_ zeigt sich die Regel, dass _-itäten_ Eigenschaften einer Person sind, während es sich bei _-ismen_ um Ideologien oder (moralische) Werte handelt.

Comment: @GrottenOlm aber das gilt nicht auch für Sexualität und Sexualismus

Comment: _Sexualismus_ ist mir jetzt kein Begriff, aber auch _Sexismus_ und _Sexualität_ sind keine Synonyme.

Comment: m.E Sexuslität wird in der Öffentlichkeit gemuzt abrer Sexismus in der Schreibensprache

Comment: sehen Sie der letzte Satz hier https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ität

Comment: @AmarAlsyed: Humorismus, Sarkasmus u.v.m. sind keine Ideologien, aber vielleicht bessere Beispiele

Comment: bis jetzt verstehe ich nicht den Unterschied zwischen -ität  und -ismus

Comment: Professionaliltät bezeichnet m.E., dass man etwas **wie** ein Berufstätiger macht, mit ähnlichem Wissen und Können (je nach Gebiet). Etwas beruflich zu tun ist die Profession, der man nachgeht.

Comment: Professionalität und Professionalismus sind nicht ganz synonym: Professionalität ist ein Grad, eine qualitative Eigenschaft, also *wie professionell* man ist, also wie gut man sich in einem professionellem Rahmen verhält. Professionalismus ist es, wenn man etwas beruflich macht, egal ob gut oder schlecht.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis was sind Ihre Quelle?

Comment: Meine Quellen? Keine besonderen. Machmal weiß man eben sowas.

Comment: @GrottenOlm: Professionalismus ist wohl kein moralischer Wert oder eine Ideologie.

Comment: @AmarAlysed: Sexismus und Sexualität sind wohl total verschiedene Begriffe, und die werden da benutzt, wo sie zutreffen, und das hat nichts mit Öffentlichkeit oder "Schreibensprache" (was das auch sein mag) zu tun. Man kann die übrigens leicht in einem Wörterbuch nachschlagen.